# How can I avoid using an interface in java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I just want to know if its possible to avoid the use of an interface in this code

```
public interface FunctionT<T,R>  {
        R apply(Integer...args);
}
public static FunctionT sum = (params) ->  Arrays.asList(params)
                                                                .stream()
                                                                .reduce(Integer::sum).get();
```

Comment: Do you know that you can use [`java.util.function.Function<Integer[], Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) instead of your own interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a lambda expression in Java is a *functional interface*.  This means that the lambda must be provided with a target type that is a functional interface.  This could be yours (`FunctionT`) or a standard one like `java.util.function.Function`.

Put another way, function types in Java are *nominal*, not structural.

(Also, you don't want to blindly call `get()` on an `Optional`, you want to use one of the safe methods like `orElse()` or `ifPresent()`.  Otherwise you lose all the safety of using `Optional` in the first place.)

Comment: +1 and I would add "with the key advantage that lambdas are structurally matched to the target nominal type".

Comment: In this case the best option would be to provide an initial value to the `reduce` method being 0.

Comment: Or maybe map to an `IntStream` (`mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`) and then just call the `sum()` method.